# Is there a drupal module for importing Facebook Events from a Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, events, drupal, calendar

My organization would like to simply list our events on our Facebook Page and have these automatically show-up on our Drupal-based website.  Is there a Drupal module that supports this (or could be configured to do so?)

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, there is no such module available in Drupal as of now.

But you can write a custom module for the same using following facebook graph api:

`https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/events`

You need a valid access token to return the events list for a page.

Visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to test it.

Answer (score 0):

good question, good usecase.
I've seen - not tried yet, the [feeds_facebook](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_facebook) module. It's a [feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module parser. It seems possible to import events.
They say:

> Example Feed URL: https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/feed
>
> Tested on Profiles and Pages. Thus, you replace {id} with profile/page
>   unique id.
>
> You might need authentication or access token using the URL. Example
>   Feed URL with authentication access token:
>   https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/feed?access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

If you give it a try, please share the results!